# Как правильно пишется – 8-й или 8-ой?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, наращение

Собственно, вопрос в самом заголовке.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: ***8-й***.

> По закрепившейся традиции наращение должно быть однобуквенным, если последней букве числительного предшествует гласный звук: *5-й день (пятый день), 25-я годовщина (двадцать пятая годовщина), в 32-м издании (в тридцать втором издании), в 14-м ряду (в четырнадцатом ряду).*

Источник: [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87).